# Will changing my Buddy Pokemon reset it's Total Kilometer walked distance?

Tags: pokemon-go

At the top of the buddy Pokemon page, there's a text indicating the total distance walked with your current buddy. Right now, I have my starter Pokemon as my buddy and got 19 kilometers walked with him. If I change my Buddy Pokemon, and then later switch it back to my starter, will this distance have reset or will it still be at 19 kilometers and continue from there?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, the total distance travelled will stay the same. The *current progress towards the next reward* **will** be reset, however.

I tried switching my Lapras out today and decided to make him my buddy again and his total distance started at 10.0 km, just as it was when I switched him out.

Answer (score 15):

The total distance walked will not change, although [current progress towards a candy will](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/285378/can-i-change-who-my-buddy-is/285379#285379).

See screenshots.  *Deathturtle* has 54.3km total and 0.3km progress towards candy.  Switching the buddy for a *Vulpix* then back to *Deathturtle* resets the progress to 0km but retains the 54.4km total.

(*I'm not sure where the extra .1km came from, I didn't move during these screenshots, perhaps a round up*)

[image: Buddy change]

Comment: Walking distances aren't updated in real-time, but periodically. Additionally, GPS location tends to wander a bit, especially if you are in or next to tall buildings. So, a combination of the two could account for suddenly finding an extra 0.1km.

Comment: Upvote for sacrificing 0.3 km.