# Will Feebas' distance travelled still count towards the evolution requirement if I unbuddy it now?

Tags: pokemon-go

Feebas can be evolved to Milotic with 100 candies after walking 20km with it.

I've walked mine 20km, but I still lack candies and I would rather walk another Pokemon until I get those 100 candies. If I unbuddy my Feebas now, do I have to walk 20km with it again when I have the candies?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Will changing my Buddy Pokemon reset it's Total Kilometer walked distance?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/285880/will-changing-my-buddy-pokemon-reset-its-total-kilometer-walked-distance)

Comment: Since Feebas/Mitotic evolution is Pokemon specific and has its own meter I don't see how the older question about total distance walked answers my question.

Comment: @Communisty It shows that the total distance walked persists when changing buddies, which is what is tracked for evolution purposes. Not sure I'd VTC as duplicate, but it's relevant.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No you are safe to equip a new buddy. I also had that problem and after achieving the required 100 candy I was free to immediately evolve my Feebas.

As credited to @yoozer8

> Note that the distance walked is tied to the specific Feebas that was
>   your buddy. If you have more than 1 (or if you hatch/catch a better
>   one later), you'll have to walk the one you want to evolve, even if
>   you've already walked another 20km

Comment: Note that the distance walked is tied to the specific Feebas that was your buddy. If you have more than 1 (or if you hatch/catch a better one later), you'll have to walk the one you want to evolve, even if you've already walked another 20km.

Comment: I will add this for sake of completion