# Why can’t I evolve my Feebas?

Tags: pokemon-go

I made it my buddy and I have 106 candies, now it says I have to walk my buddy 20 more km.

So I removed my buddy and replaced it with something else and it still would not evolve, can someone help?

Comment: It said you had to walk it another 20 km. Did you do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Will Feebas' distance travelled still count towards the evolution requirement if I unbuddy it now?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/332646/will-feebas-distance-travelled-still-count-towards-the-evolution-requirement-if)

Answer (score 9):

To evolve a Feebas you need to have walked it 20km as well as have the required 100 candies.

There is a tracker bar under on every Feebas showing your progress towards the 20km requirement, once this has been filled it can be evolved. See below: 
[image: http://www.ign.com/wikis/pokemon-go/How_How_to_Evolve_Every_Pokemon_in_Pokemon_Go]

Answer (score -3):

To evolve feebas you need to do both of the following:

- Attain 100 feebas candies
- Make Feebas your buddy and walk with him 20 km

Comment: This does not add any new information that has already been stated in the other answer