# I walked 20 km with feebas in Pokemon go and I still didn't get 100 candies. Why?

Tags: pokemon-go

My Feebas is of 140 cp, my current level is 28.
I walked 20 km with Feebas in Pokemon go and I still didn't get 100 candies.

Can somebody help me with what problem I might be having?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can’t I evolve my Feebas?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/333292/why-can-t-i-evolve-my-feebas)

Comment: I don't think this is a dupe. My interpretation is that OP either misunderstood or was misinformed about feebas and walking 20km. I think they thought they'd get 100 candies for walking.

Answer (score 11):

That's not how this works.

Feebas doesn't give you 100 candies for walking it 20km. Walking 20km is a requirement to be able to evolve the Feebas, as well as having 100 candies.

You'll need to get 100 candies yourself, in the same way you'd get them for any pokemon. You could walk more with Feebas, use rare candy, and/or catch more Feebases.