# Evolving Feebas

Tags: pokemon-go

When trying to evolve Feebas into Milotic in Pokemon GO, you can either use 100 Feebas Candies to evolve it, or it says:

> Walk with you buddy to evolve this Pokemon

There is then a progress bar underneath, which you can fill by walking with Feebas as a buddy, and it becomes full once you've walked 20Km.

I've now filled this bar by walking the 20Km, but Feebas still hasn't evolved. What do I need to do in order to evolve it?

Comment: [This question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/333292/20456) is pretty related.

Comment: @Frank the question is asking something else, probably why I couldn’t find it, but it seems the answer provides what I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not an *or* it is an *and*. You need to have 100 candies and have had to have walked 20km with your Feebas before you can make that final plunge and evolve into a Milotic.

**Edit:** You must have 20km distance on the Feebas you want to evolve i.e. A Feebas' distance bar must be full before evolving.

Comment: Thank you, I feel like it’s quite vague on what it wants you to do, but now it makes more sense.

Comment: You are welcome... however it is appreciated if you do a bit more research first in future. There are already two other really similar questions on Arquade